# Add list web part to content editor table (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, web, table

Is there a way to add a list web part into one of the cells in a table that exists in a content editor web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just edit page without Content Editor Web part. So you can add table to the page (without Content Editor Web part) then add web parts to each cell.

Comment: Once I created a new page, this was able to be done.  Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the page in Advanced mode in SharePoint Designer, find the cell of the table, insert a Data View web part and select the relevant list.

[image]

Comment: This was also a viable option, once a new page was created.  Thanks.